# How to guarantee that a script in the middle of the body runs after all the DOM has finished load

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

In my `<body>` I have a component that inserts a script that is supposed to run only after all the page has completely loaded:

```
<script>
    $('<script id="smallPlacarScriptdId">\
$(window).load(function() {\
        $(".main.right").hide();\                                                 
        $("#rightzero").show();\
        $(".comp.smallPlacard.firstChild").click(function () {\
            var clicked = $(this).parent().attr("id");\
            $("main.right").hide();\
            $("#right"+clicked+"").show();\
        });\
})\
    <\script>').appendTo("body")
</script>
```

That's not happening and this script (1) is correctly inserted into the DOM but (2) is not working  (not hiding .main.right nor showing #rightzero).
I though that by using this approach I would guarantee that it would be the same as just put this script at the bottom of the `<body>` but it isn't. In fact if I put it (not dynamically like this) in my page it produces the desired result.
I tried `setTimeout()` to validate my theory but I'm getting an error in jQuery and I'm lost.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "not working" - it's not running at all, or it's running immediately? 2. What is the "error in jQuery"? 3. Any other errors in your [JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)?

Comment: I can see the html parser doing a number to that piece of code. (Hint `<\script>`)

Comment: @PaulRoub 1. It doesn't hide/show the elements. 2. "Unexpected end of script" in the middle of the jQuery library itself. 3. No

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That might be the problem:

```
<\script>').appendTo("body")
```

Browser might think you are actually closing your script tag. Change it to

```
</' + 'script>').appendTo("body")
```

Check this plunker out: http://plnkr.co/edit/Oc6yrFMdPoW2WV257CBQ?p=preview

Comment: You're right that I have a problem with the closing tag, but either way when inspecting the code I can see a closing <script> tag with  my code and a </script> tag with your code. And still doesn't work...

Comment: I would do it but I'm using Phoenix framework with server side components...Nevertheless I'll take a few more minutes to follow your lead because it really must be something related with that. I'll get back after a few more tries. Thanks!

Comment: just updated the answer with the plunker link again. Please check the link out.

Comment: Yes! I know it should work with your code. So I'm just going back in my git to clean potential mistakes making while trying to find the solution and using a previous version (very complex page :)

Comment: Finally...working! You were correct (as expected) but I had a space in my `.class.class.class .class`that was preventing the code to work and no errors giving...thanks again!

Comment: i'm glad that it helped :)

Comment: Ah that's bitten me numerous times.  Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't read you question well enough.

Javascript will allow you to access undeclared variables, so use that to your advantage.   Check if a variable is set, undefined is treated as a false so no need for initialization.  As soon as you enter the code just set it to true so nothing else will execute.

Hopefully this solves the problem for you, but you really should look at from the server avoiding the javascript, it will bloat the page.

```
<script>
    if (!myScriptHasLoaded)
    {
        myScriptHasLoaded = true;
        $(window).load(function() {
            $("main.right").hide();                                                 
            $("#rightzero").show();
            $(".comp.smallPlacard.firstChild").click(function () {
                var clicked = $(this).parent().attr("id");
                $("main.right").hide();
                $("#right"+clicked+"").show();
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm appending it because  I'm inserting several of these components on the same page and I just want to have one script, not N scripts that do exactly the same . By inserting this way I can dos this:    ` if (document.getElementById('smallPlacarScriptdId')){}            // <style> is only created on first component instanciation to avoid duplication
    else {\\my code here}`

Comment: Thank you Vince. You're correct. Btw, do you have an idea about the cost of having this script 20 times in one page? A part from not being elegant is there a real performance cost?

Comment: Ah, sorry I was a bit blind on that.  Let me see if I can come up with some options for you.

Comment: Page size would be one of the biggest concerns.  Multiple version of the script executing would put a minor load from an execution point.  Finding/replacing the script over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code

```
<script id="smallPlacarScriptdId">
$(window).load(function() {
    $("main.right").hide();                                            
    $("#rightzero").show();
    $(".comp.smallPlacard.firstChild").click(function () {
        var clicked = $(this).parent().attr("id");
        $("main.right").hide();
        $("#right"+clicked+"").show();
    });
})
</script>
```

Comment: You are right. But I explain above why in this particular case I want this. Thank you.